# Flushing node.js socker writes

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a node.js sample where a client socket makes two writes to a server. I'm trying to make sure the server receives the writes one by one, using the socket.write with a callback:

```
var net = require('net');

const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = 7000;

var server = new net.Server(socket => {
    socket.on('data', data => {
        console.log("Server received: " + data);
    })
});
server.listen(PORT, HOST);

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST);
client.write("call 1", "utf8", () => {
    client.write("call 2");
});
```

When I run it I get output:

```
Server received: call 1call 2
```

According to the docs here https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback:

> ... The optional callback parameter will be executed when the data is finally written out...

What does *data is finally written out* mean? How can I make the server produce:

```
Server received: call 1
Server received: call 2
```

Thanks,
Dinko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a stream. It does not know anything about the beginning and end of your messages.

1. You need to add delimiter (eg `\n`: `client.write("call 2\n");`)
2. You need split data by delimiter on the receiver (eg node split package).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout for the second event.

```
client.write("call 1", "utf8")
setTimeout(() => {
   client.write("call 2");
 }, 100);
```